# How to delete a strange white bar over my map Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a WPF application with Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF everything works fine, but appear an anoying white bar, like the goggle search bar, over my map, right on the middle like you  can see in the image below
[image]

the code in xaml that shows the map is this:

```
            <m:Map Grid.Row="1" x:Name="mapTodos"  
               Margin="5"  
               CredentialsProvider="myValidKey" 
               Mode="Road" 
               ZoomLevel="15" Center="-17.7891963,-63.1885567"/>
```

Any idea about this issue?

thanks in advance

Comment: Did you try to refresh it somewhere from code when you render it? myMap.Refresh(); Does this happen on full screen or on loading?

Comment: I have a button and in the click() event, at code behind, I create all the points. 
It is not on full screen, It is allocated on a Grid that shows or hides when some buttons are pressed.
I didn't found a Refresh() method for  Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF.Map I'm using nugget Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF ver. 1.0.0.3 (the last one) with .Net framework 4.7.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your `CredentialsProvider` `Key`!!!
After implementing the same map in a simple Grid layout panel I got them working(same settings as yours) and after I modified the the provider key I got the same white bar with a message which can mean that you have something defined in your style which can cause a problem. Check my attached images and a clip.

Besides that, I did some research:

1. Error handling - Implement error handling in your code to catch and display any exceptions that may be occurring during the loading of map data. This can help you pinpoint the source of the issue.
2. Map Size and Position - Check the size and positioning of your Bing Maps control. Incorrect sizing or positioning can result in rendering issues. Ensure that the map control is properly placed within your layout.
3. Tile Loading - If you have custom tile layers or overlays, ensure that they are implemented correctly and not causing rendering issues. These can sometimes lead to white bars.
4. Theming and Styles - Check whether any custom styles or theming in your application are affecting the map rendering. Simplify your styles if necessary.
5. Map Events - Review the map events in your application. Events like Loaded, ViewChangeEnd, and others can be used to control map behavior. Make sure they are not causing the issue.
6. UI Rendering Issues - If the white bar appears during the rendering of the map, it could be related to UI rendering. Check if you have any UI-related issues, such as incorrect sizing or positioning of the map control, which could cause white bars.

So, to confirm, invalid key will not show it in designer but in runtime it will...[image]

[image]

Finally, if I correct my key it works.
Basically that is a placeholder of an Bing maps error in your code(which should have a message).